Why do I have to use an intermediate variable in Perl when JSON-decoding a file with newlines?
I'm using the read_file sub from the File::Slurp module and the decode_json sub from the JSON module to easily read the contents of a file for JSON decoding. However, I found that when my file contains newlines, I can't directly pass the return value of read_file to decode_json, as I receive an error regarding invalid JSON. Instead, I have to store the return value of read_file into a variable before passing it.
I'm still pretty new to Perl (using v5.30 or v5.38 depending on system), and coming from languages like JS and Python this surprises me; why is this intermediate variable assignment required? Not that this isn't an easy enough workaround, just looking to satisfy my curiosity.
Example:
use v5.38;
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Slurp qw( read_file );
use JSON        qw( decode_json );

my $contents = read_file('test.json');
my $decoded  = decode_json($contents);
say "Decoded contents";

my $chained_decoded = decode_json( read_file('test.json') );
say "Decoded chained contents";

Alongside a file test.json with the contents:
[{ "a": "b" }, { "b": "c" }]

This causes no errors, and both logs show up.
However, with the contents:
[
    { "a": "b" },
    { "b": "c" }
]

I see the first log, but then the error , or ] expected while parsing array, at character offset 2 (before "(end of string)") at test.pl line 12. is thrown

read_file is documented as being context-sensitive: in scalar context it returns the entire contents of the file as one string. In list context it returns a list of lines.
The arguments list of a function call is a list context, but decode_json doesn't want a list of lines, it wants the whole file in the first argument and ignores the rest.
You can force scalar context by writing decode_json(scalar read_file('test.json')).

Ahh I was missing the fact that the arguments are implicitly a list context, thank you! Out of curiosity, why does that not result in some sort of type mismatch error? Does Perl perform an implicit conversion of a list to a string? I realize this could be entirely dependent on that subroutine's specific logic, like if it thinks it's iterating the characters of a string but instead gets elements of an array. But then I guess I'm confused why it works as expected when the list only has one element (i.e. no newlines)

@awarrier99, Note that File::Slurper has a better interface than File::Slurp, and its read_text returns the entire file even in list context.

@awarrier99 Re "like if it thinks it's iterating the characters of a string but instead gets elements of an array", It doesn't get an array. (In fact, it's impossible to pass an array to a sub.) It gets multiple strings. /// Re "Does Perl perform an implicit conversion of a list to a string?" No. There's no conversion. There's no "list of strings". There's just multiple strings. And decode_json only looks at the first one.

@ikegami Thanks for the tip, I'll look into that module. And right that makes sense, I forgot you can only pass a list ref as an argument, otherwise it is interpreted as spread arguments

array reference

@awarrier99 an argument list is a list. An argument list with one thing in it is just thatL an argument list with one thing in it. Lists aren't arrays. Lists are everywhere in Perl, and they're handy, but if you start thinking of them as equivalent to something in any other language, you're probably wrong.

@ikegami & hobbs, thanks for that clarification, I definitely had been conflating the two, but you both led me to some good reading on the underlying behavior of Perl

Well, I have to disagree with @hobbs. There's a list operator (,). There's a list context. But otherwise, lists are nowhere in Perl. When we say "list (of scalars)", it's simply a shorthand for something like "some possibly non-unary number of scalars". When we say read_file returns a list, we just means it's not bound to return a single scalar.

@ikegami makes sense; the gist of what I understood from what I read was that lists are Perl's internal representation of some ordered scalars, and arrays are the developer-facing construct for leveraging lists. So I guess in that sense couldn't you say that lists are almost nowhere where the developer is concerned, but everywhere where the language is concerned?

Nope. List don't have anything to do with arrays. They don't even exist. They're just an abstraction for scalars on the stack. They're very much the opposite of internal since they only exist in our minds.

@ikegami I see, but doesn't Perl have to use some sort of list-like data structure to track things like how many scalar values there are? Or is it more akin to Assembly/machine code where this is represented by a segment of the stack between memory pointers

@awarrier99 that's almost exactly it. Whenever you see a list, it's just some scalars on the stack, and there's another stack called the "mark stack" that stores counts, so that things can pop the correct number of items off of the value stack. That's why lists are fleeting things. There are no list variables, and from some perspectives there are no list values either.

Ah awesome that makes a lot more sense now, thanks for the detailed explanation!

Re "but doesn't Perl have to use some sort of list-like data structure to track things like how many scalar values there are?", No. it has a long stack with all the scalars, and another that marks the start of stack frames. Consider @c = ( @a, @b, f() ); In the "list" model, you think that @a, @b and f() return lists, but that's a lie. The mark is added by =, and @a, @b and f() simply add to the stack.

@ikegami in your example there, the values for @a, @b, and the return value of f() are already on the stack, right? So when I subsequently do the "list concatenation" (I know it's not really that, not sure what else to call it) of @c, are those scalar values copied to one contiguous block or is the mark stack somehow tracking that this list spans different locations on the stack

Again, there's no list being returned and concatenated. There's only scalars being pushed onto the stack. In order: 0) [The top of the stack is already marked.] 1) @a adds to the stack. 2) @b adds to the stack.  3) f() adds to the stack. 4) A reference to @c is added to the stack. 5) = copies the elements from the mark to the current top of the stack into @c and pops them. This leaves the stack (incl marks) in the state as it was at the beginning of this code.

@ikegami Got it, step 5 there is what made that click for me - I was thinking that the values are always referenced from the stack. So when you say it's copied into @c, is that heap storage?

All Perl variables except 4 exist in the heap, yes. (The 4 are the undef, the false, the true, and the zero. (Other scalars can have these values too. These are specific, highly-reused, immortal scalars. ) ) These might be allocated in static memory.

@ikegami good to know. I know I took this discussion way beyond the scope of the original question, but I appreciate you both going in depth; I've had struggles with the nuances of Perl but it's slowly becoming clearer

Oh and just for completeness's sake, I wanted to confirm that both the scalar and File::Slurper approaches worked perfectly for me. I ended up going with the File::Slurper module because imo that makes the code more readable and less error-prone (if things get moved around or refactored) for current and future devs
